# How to display custom widget anywhere

Tags: widgets, widget-text

I've a custom widget for ads, it helps me to show ads on sidebar but I'm trying to display it under every single post or on front page near to slider.

```
<?php the_widget( 'AdWidget_300' ); ?>
```

How could I call custom widget anywhere I want?

Comment: You can filter the_content and return it after the content and use a conditional tag is_front_page(); OR you can call the sidebar in your single.php or content.php file

Comment: Had this quesiton been resolved?

Answer (score 4):

[Add a widget area](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes) to your `single.php`, `front-page.php`, `home.php` or whatever you want.. template's theme file. Than at the back-end go to Appearance > Widgets and move the widget to the widget area you just created.

Comment: now another issue sticked to my mind, was it possible to display 5 ads using one widget but for different placement? or did i need to use one widget for one ads. Total i'll have to create 5 widgets for my ads

Comment: @Bergmann, you can create as many widgets and widget areas as you want.

Answer (score 3):

We can't display custom widget directly in content or any other place. `the_widget()` function only display built-in widget.

But still if you want display custom widget then you must create sidebar and assign widget to newly created sidebar and display that sidebar using `dynamic_sidebar( 'id' );`.

For more information http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes

Answer (score 2):

Custom widget works well with `<?php the_widget( '' ); ?>`

You can test it.

1. Copy widget example  https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Displaying_Widgets
2. Don't forget register as say in codex `add_action( 'widgets_init', ...`
3. Call it from index.php `<?php the_widget( 'Foo_Widget' ); ?>`

Comment: how would I find out the name of a widget? I'm using the Rey Theme and it offers a widget to display products.  I'm writing custom code and want to include it but don't know the name of the widget

Comment: look at the code inside.

Answer (score 1):

@Bergmann,It is possible to display 5 ads in single page using single widget "if all ads are together" . But if you want all ads at different places , you have to create different widget areas and different widgets .

Answer (score 1):

A clean, simple, and easy solution to your question is to look into the [amr shortcode any widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amr-shortcode-any-widget/). As the name suggests, you can insert your widgets in your pages by using shortcodes, like so:

```
[do_widget "Your Widget" ]
```